# Frequency of visiting states in Markov chains

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

Given a finite, ergodic Markov $\{X_i\}$, and two natural numbers $a>b$. Let

$$p=P\left[\forall n, \sum_{k=n}^{n+a-1} \mathbf{1}_m(X_k)\leq b\right]$$
where $\mathbf{1}_m(X_k) =1$ if $X_k=m$ and 0 otherwise.

Namely, $p$ is the probability that for any time interval of size $a$, the number of visits to state $m$ is less than or equal to $b$.

The question is the property of $p$ and how to compute it.

Obviously this questions is related to the limited distribution (which, by ergodicity, is equivalent to the stationary distribution), but I could not find the exact link, since stationary distribution talks about the limit, but here, the size of interval is finite. Moreover, I am not sure whether this type of questions has been studied. References would be appreciated. 
(Note: some imprecision has been corrected, according to an earlier answer.)

Answer (score 5):

An ergodic finite Markov chain satisfies a $0-1$ law.
If it is possible (i.e. probability $> 0$) to have more than $b$ visits to state $m$ in a time interval of length $a$, then with probability $1$ this will eventually happen.  If it is not possible, then of course the probability is $0$.

EDIT:

Let $p_1$ be the probability, starting from state $m$, of having more than $b$ visits to state $m$ in the time interval $[0,a]$.  Of course, if $p_1 = 0$, the probability of ever having more than $b$ visits to state $m$ in a time interval of length $a$ is $0$.  Now suppose $p_1 > 0$.  Since the Markov chain is ergodic, it will almost surely visit state $m$  infinitely many times.  Let $T_1$ be the first time it visits state $m$, and $T_j$ for $j > 1$ the first time it visits state $m$ after $T_{j-1}+a$.  Let $A_j$ be the event of having more than $b$  visits to state $m$ in time interval $[T_j, T_j+a]$.  By the Markov property and stationarity, $A_j$ are independent, and each has probability $p_1$, so with probability $1$ infinitely many of them will occur.

Comment: I don't see any events in this question about which it would be immediately clear that they are tail.

Comment: Hmm, OK, I'll reformulate my answer.

Answer (score 3):

You don't actually formulate your question, but I presume that you want to know about the probability $p=p(a,b,m)$ (strictly speaking, one has to specify the measure $P$ on the path space, but in fact it does not matter).

The answer is entirely combinatorial - the only thing one has to know about the transition probabilities is the minimal number of steps $T=T(m)$ necessary to return to the state $m$ with positive probability. Then, on one hand, in any sample path any two consecutive occurrences of $m$ will be distanced by at least $T$, and, on the other hand, by ergodicity almost every sample path will contain arbitrary long time intervals with every $T$-th state being $m$, which will give an answer to your question: this probability is either 0 or 1 depending on an explicit relationship between $a$ and $b$. For instance, if $T(m)=1$, then $p=1$ if and only if $b=a$.

By the way, if you want to talk about time intervals of length $a$, then the summation in the definition of $p$ should be from $k=n$ to $k=n+a-1$. There is also an inconsistency between your formula for $p$ (where the sum is $\le b$) and the sentence just below where you ask for the number of visits to be strictly less than $b$.

Comment: Many thanks for pointing out the mistakes in the formulation of the problem. I do not quite understand the statement "if T(m)=1, then p=1 if and only if b≤a". Say, the chain has only state m, and loop there; a=2>b=1. Obviously T(m)=1, and according to your claim, p=1, but obviously in this case, p=0 as the only sample path is m forever.

Comment: Sorry - got lost in the inequalities :) So, if $T=1$, then for any $a$ a.e. sample path contains a length $a$ interval which consists of $m$'s, so that $p=0$ for $b=0,1,\dots,a-1$ and $p=1$ for $b=1$.